# Compass and http_images_path

Tags: image, http, path, compass-geolocation

I'm on compass 0.12.2...I'm trying to use the the config reference http_images_path in the config.rb but it doesn't look like it is using this reference...it still resolves the image to my local directory...am I missing something?

Thanks for any help!!

**Config.rb**

```
http_path = "/"
# Get the directory that this configuration file exists in
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
# Compass configurations
sass_path = dir
css_path = File.join(dir, "..", "css")
#images_dir = "../resources/images"
http_images_path = "http://myurl/img/"
output_style = :expanded
environment = :development
```

**css file:**

```
@import "compass";

.dir
{
  background: image-url("guide.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on compass watch...you need to restart to have updated config.rb take effect.